# Line integral along Circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Can you please give me a hint so that I can get started with the following integral?

$$\oint_{C(R)} \frac{\sin(\pi/z)}{(1+z)^2} dz$$

where $C(R)$ is a circle with radius $R$ and origin $0$. Calculate for $R>1$ that integral. 
I have never done such an integral before so any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What have you done so far? Naively I would have thought you would use the residue theorem and considering the singularities are at $0$ and $-1$, the condition that $R>1$ is _required_ in order to evaluate the integral around all the poles. However, I could be wrong as I'm a bit rusty in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps. $$\sin(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dots$$ $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right) = \frac{\pi}{z}-\frac{\pi^3}{3! \cdot z^3} + \dots$$ $$\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-z^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-z^2)^n = 1 -z^2 + z^4 -\dots$$ Multiply the two series together, look for just the coefficients on the $z^{-1}$ group these together and multiply by $2\pi i$. I'm getting $$\oint_{C_R} \frac{\sin(\pi/z)}{1+z^2} dz = 2\pi i \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$